# How to best set the path to java in windows

Tags: java, windows, path

I'm curious about the difference that exists between the paths that I see in the windows environment to java. 
If I do a command `where java` I can see

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\java.exe
```

And I have seen that the first one, the javapath, gets updated with the latest java sdk I have installed. However, most of what you google tells you should set the environment variable PATH to the latest, the one with the jdk in the path. 
So what is the best, how do they work. For example, what's best for Xamarin or Android development?

Hopefully someone has some insight, I'd appreciate comments on this.
Now I know, (everyone does) that to change the path to java you have to set the JAVA_HOME variable. I did this after posting this, it's hard to recall everything you read at any given moment! 
Still what's the purpose of the other paths, and why does updating java jre automatically sets the java version while downloading an sdk requires a manual update?

Comment: Relevant investigation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49540325/which-jre-does-c-programdata-oracle-java-javapath-java-exe-use/49543305

Answer (score 17):

When a new version of JRE is installed, this path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java` appears to be updated with executables corresponding to the new JRE version. The problem is this would be **JRE** and not **JDK**. So, programs that depend on JDK (IDE for example) will fail to launch.

**Here is how I get it to work consistently**

1. I always have an environment variable in *User Variables* (System Environment Variables by going to Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables ->  User Variables) -- `JAVA_HOME` pointing to the **JDK** Home. And add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the `PATH` environment variable.
2. Interestingly, I remove the entry `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` from the `Path` environment variable in *System Environment Variables* (Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables ->  System Variables).

This works as of Aug 2020 for Windows 10 (1903), Java 8u251. :)

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` is being added to env variables as first entry. I'll disable auto updates. I have no idea how it's updated

Comment: Adding %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the PATH environment variable definitely worked fır me.

Comment: I have not been able to find the javapath configured in my System Env Variables for the Admin account. I had to set the PATH manually as you described until `where java` returned the right JDK only. Afterwards I searched my Control Panel and found the Java Control Panel which has the references to `javaw.exe`. Dunno if this is related.

Comment: It is imperative to remove `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` and other java paths from path environment variables, leaving only the **%JAVA_HOME%\bin**

Answer (score 1):

On my machine, the files in C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath used to symlink to files elsewhere.  But noticed this has changed in or before 8u112.  Worth noting that on my current release (8u171) both javapath folders symlink to "target" folders in the same directory.

If I undo the things in c:\programdata I notice that my Eclipse environment stops working well.

But I don't have much more insight on the history or why behind all of this though.

Answer (score 0):

I just moved `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to before the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` and it works without any problem. I suggest you to check your environment variables and your Path variable regularly, especially after you install something on your machine.