# Issues with running java from the command prompt

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables, command-prompt, javac

I am having issues running java from the command prompt. I believe it may be something to do with setting up the environment variables. I am using windows 10.

I have a simple java code that prints the word "yes"

when I try the following this happens:

```
> javac test.java
>
>java test
>
```

whereas when I try:

```
> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\javac.exe" test.java
>
> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java" test
> yes
```

It works

my path and java home look as follows:

```
>echo %JAVA_HOME%
>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2
>echo %PATH%
>C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin;C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
```

Any help would be appreciated :) thank you

Comment: What's in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`?

Comment: @akuzminykh java, javac, javaw, jshell. I also have a Program Files (x86) directory if this helps

Comment: Move `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin;` right at the beginning in `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing below entry to use manual jdk path only.

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

refer [How to best set the path to java in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50055291/how-to-best-set-the-path-to-java-in-windows)

not sure which installation you've but you can find more info here

https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2412304_1.html