# Installation and launch of payara not working

Tags: java, powershell, batch-file, environment, payara

I have to install and launch Payara for a project but at launch using the command .\asadmin.bat start-domain and the result is this:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Files
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files

[image]

I checked the java version, and the environment variables if they were set correctly.
I also checked the log files to see any errors but none were present. I checked if port 4848 was busy but it is free.

[image] [image]

I also checked the domain.xml file and I think the port configuration is correct.
logically I started power shell as administrator to do all this but I can't understand how to solve the problem.

Comment: `echo` is a `cmd.exe` internal command. You however are using `powershell.exe`. In PowerShell to see the value of a system environment variable you'd use, ```$Env:JAVA_HOME``` or ```[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('JAVA_HOME')```, not ```echo %JAVA_HOME%```.

Comment: Thanks, yes now the result is PS C:\Users\Edwar\Downloads\payara-5.2022.5\payara5\bin> $Env:JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.17

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50055291/how-to-best-set-the-path-to-java-in-windows

Comment: I suggest to remove the ` C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` entry from your PATH and try again. Maybe there's another installation in the way.

Comment: done every step suggested but nothing, it remains like this. I installed a virtual machine with Win 11 to test it and everything goes smoothly there

Comment: aside from reinstalling the JDK I have no more ideas - you could trace the whole thing with Sysinternals ProcMon of course