# Switching to java 11 from java 8

Tags: java, windows, java-11

I have downloaded and installed oraclejdk11 from oracle official site and modified PATH & JAVA_HOME variable in system environment variable on windows

C:\Users\Aviral>javac -version

**javac 11.0.1**

C:\Users\Aviral>java -version

**java version "1.8.0_102"**

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)

i know that jdk11 do not contain jre but how can i run a java program from cmd in java 11

Comment: In bin path it is showing java version as 11.01 but how do i execute a program from another folder using java 11

Comment: When you setting JAVA_HOME and PATH, you can access java command globally (means you can use it in any path).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The JDK includes the JRE which you can launch by using the `java` executable in the `bin` folder. You use this executable just like any other executable.

When you type `java` in the command line it is actually shorthand. It searches your `PATH` until it finds the first matching `java` executable. If you want to specify a different `java` executable you can give the absolute path to the executable.

```
C:\Users\Avril> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\java" -jar path\to\file.jar
```

You may be wondering, if you've set `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` to point to JDK-11, why does `java -version` still use Java 8?

Take a look at your `PATH` and you'll likely find something like `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` as one of the first entries ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51457823/6395627)). This entry was added automatically when you installed Java 8 and points to the Java 8 executables (`java`, `javaw`, and `javaws`). Since it's before your `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` entry, it takes precedence. However, `...\javapath` doesn't contain `javac` and that's why `javac -version` used `JAVA_HOME` (Java 11).

Comment: My path variable only contains path of jdk11 bin folder

Comment: Then I'd assume `java` would not be using Java 8. Somewhere, something must be pointing to Java 8. If not, then maybe your environment hasn't been "refreshed".

Comment: Thanks @Slaw. I wasted long time to find out why `java -version` does not show Java 11 even after setting the right path to the bin. Removing `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` from the path variable worked!

Comment: how to switch to java 11 by default while having multiple java version installed

Comment: @neo As long as your PATH points to Java 11, then using `java` on the command line should use version 11 "by default". If you have multiple entries in your PATH pointing to different Java installations, using `java` on the command line will always use the first matching entry.

Answer (score 8):

bin folder contains all the traditional JRE tools. In Java 11, both JDK and JRE tools are consolidated so that there is no JRE within JDK 11.

Answer (score 2):

In order to execte program from another folder than bin using java 11 you must set the JAVA_HOME path as follows **from CMD**:

Open CMD as Administrator

Set JAVA_HOME to JDK 11 bin folder

```
setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program File\Java\..."
```

Comment: i used the command and got "SUCCESS: result value has been saved" but still getting java 1-8 as java version

Comment: Because it's wrong. You don't set it to the bin folder. Use the jdk folder.

Comment: Moving C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath to the bottom , under Java 11 path solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to JDK 11 from JDK 8. After adding Java 11 to the path [ point path up to

bin foler ] and JAVA_HOME [ only upto jdk folder **(don't include bin )** ]

successfully,

`java -version` was still pointing to the previous java version (java 8 in my case.)

Then, I ran a command `"setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.7"`

Now `java -version` or `javac -version` both  shows java 11.

I hope it helps you too.