# Best method to install an Oracle JRE without changing Default Java?

Tags: java, oracle, installation

I want to install Oracle JRE 1.8.202 x64 without making any changes to the current default java on target machines.

Detail on what I mean by 'Default Java'. I mean I don't want the installer to change of any of the settings that any current or old Java installer may have made to make itself the default (e.g. path changes, java executables dumped in `windows` or `system32` directories, `java.exe` added or updated to `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe`, environment variables like `JAVA.HOME`, Java executables added to registry apppaths).

The target machines are a mix of Windows machines that will have a huge variety of current Java installations. Some apps in the target environment rely on using the default java to run - I'd rather they didn't, but that's out of my control.

I can't see any options to stop the installer (jre-8u202-windows-x64.exe) setting it's JRE to the default. See the installer switches at [Oracle JavaSE 8 Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/config.html#table_config_file_options).

Anyone know of any methods other then just copying the files into a target directory?

Snapshotting the current default then restoring it is not an option - Oracle have changed 'setting the default' technique over time, so restoring cleanly would be a fragile rabbit hole.

Comment: Don't. Install the JDK *without* installing the JRE that comes with the JDK. The JDK is not put on the PATH, but it *embeds* the full JRE.

Comment: @Andreas, see the text above, it's a JRE I need, not a JDK.

Comment: But the JDK ***embeds*** a JRE, so you get the JRE without the installer messing with the PATH.

Comment: Thanks. If the JDK does not update the java defaults, then this would work if disk space was not an unknown across my target estate. The JDK is likely to be too big for me to risk it without impact.

Answer (score 0):

For both JDK and JRE installations, Oracle differentiates between "patch in place" and "static" installations, where the former refers to updating an existing JRE with newer components in an existing directory, and the latter refers to performing a standalone install.

You want to run the install via command line:

```
jre-8u251-windows-i586.exe f:\jre_config_file
```

where `jre-8u251-windows-i586.exe` is the latest version of JRE 8 (of course you can specify whatever flavor of JRE 8 you're actually after), `f:\jre_config_file` is a file containing the line `STATIC=1` and any other config options you're after.

You could also just feed the installer `STATIC=1` as a command line arg.

The `STATIC` option is actually listed in the page you linked, so I'll spare you additional blather about config.

Comment: I'll try the `STATIC` option. I did see the option it in the Oracle doc, but didn't see anything about whether it will avoid setting/altering any existing default java settings (i.e. no changing the path, no dumping it's exe in `windows` or `system32` dirs, no updating the `java.exe` in `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe`, no setting environment variables, no adding to registry apppaths).

Comment: @DavidGibson In the future, it would be helpful to include detailed requirements in the initial question, as opposed to adding them via comment, after the fact.

Comment: I've added that list of java installer 'set itself as the default' techniques into the main question. It's just a list of techniques I've come across, it may not be spot on.

Comment: I tried the `STATIC` option in combination with other low impact settings. Unfortunately, it did not work. It still added all the Java default executable environment, junction and registry entries detailed at [which-jre-does-c-programdata-oracle-java-javapath-java-exe-use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49540325/which-jre-does-c-programdata-oracle-java-javapath-java-exe-use). Full command line was `jre-8u251-windows-x64.exe AUTO_UPDATE=Disable INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251" INSTALL_SILENT=Enable NOSTARTMENU=Enable STATIC=Enable WEB_ANALYTICS=Disable WEB_JAVA=Disable`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the best method but you could try using [SDKMan](https://sdkman.io/install) to manage your Java versions on your target machine.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a managed way to use the installer without changing target system default java.

Instead, a custom installation process copies the installation tree into the target directory. Works fine.