# Why are there 2 Java platform binaries running for one java program on Windows 10?

Tags: java, jvm, windows-10

I have this simple java command line application

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Hello World !");
        System.in.read();
}
```

When I start it on Windows 10, Windows Task Manager displays two instances of java.exe as subprocesses of the Windows Command Prompt process:

1. **Java(TM) Platform SE binary** from

> C:\Program Files\Common
> Files\Oracle\Java\javapath_target_383000\java.exe

2. **OpenJDK Platform binary** from

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin\java.exe

[image]

One should think one instance of the JVM should be enough to run this program, so why are there two ?

Edit: I compiled this program against a JDK 1.8.0 (instead of JDK 15.0.1) and now only the Java(TM) Platform SE binary shows up.

Comment: They are most probably two different running Java processes running two different Java programs!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose : no - because when the program exits, they both disappear

Comment: Yes, because one Java program only runs in one Java process! So it must be something else. Your assumption is wrong!

Comment: There's definitely only one Java program running in this Windows command shell

Comment: What does `where java` print? Perhaps the javapath_target_383000 version is an unnecessary wrapper which launches the other.

Comment: `where java` prints `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin\java.exe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a feature of Oracle's installer for Java on Windows. The installer adds the folder `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath_target` to the `PATH` variable. This folder contains a symlink to a java.exe executable in another folder. This executable detects the location of the latest/configured JRE  version by checking the registry and JAVA_HOME. Then it calls java.exe of the actual JRE. So the first java.exe is not a real JVM but a simple native app that gets executed, when you call java within the console. To avoid the usage of this mechanism simply replace the javapath_target folder with the folder of your JRE within the PATH environment variable. For a more detailed description see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51457823/13510562) answer.